# How to lengthen the UISearchBar in x direction with animation?

Tags: ios, core-animation, uisearchbar

I want to lengthen the right search bar 20 px to the left, and shorten left search bar 20 px to the right with animation. How can I do that?

```
CGRect leftFrame = self.leftSearchBar.frame;
    //leftFrame.origin.x = leftFrame.origin.x - 20;
    leftFrame.size.width = leftFrame.size.width - 40;

    CGRect rightFrame = self.rightSearchBar.frame;
    rightFrame.origin.x = rightFrame.origin.x - 40;
    rightFrame.size.width = rightFrame.size.width + 40;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    self.leftSearchBar.frame = leftFrame;
    self.rightSearchBar.frame = rightFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

It doesn't work. It first resizes views without animation, then moves the right view with animation.

Comment: "It doesn't work. It first resizes views without animation, then moves the right view with animation." Are you changing the frames anywhere else? This may interfere with the animation.

Comment: No. Just changing in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've not changed the anchor points, or anything like that, simply expanding the width will make it stretch to the right. Wrap this within a UIView animation block, and it should animate according to the specification within the question, as so:

```
UISearchBar* searchbar = ...; // However you've created your UISearchBar, we'll refer to it as 'searchbar'

CGRect searchFrame = searchbar.frame;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     searchFrame.size.width += 30;
                     searchbar.frame = searchFrame;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

You'll need to make sure the `+= 30` doesn't get called more than once, as otherwise you'll be expanding by 30 points **each time** this is called. If you know the size before hand, you could simply substitute it with `= size + 30`, which is a safer bet incase you call the animation more than once.

Comment: You can't directly manipulate any of the frame properties, so searchbar.frame.size.width += 30; won't work. The best would be to assign it to a variable: CGRect searchFrame = searchbar.frame; searchFrame.size.width += 30; [searchbar setFrame:searchFrame];

Comment: I am getting error here `searchFrame.size.width += 30;` that says read only variable is not assignable?.

Comment: @icodes Don't modify the frame directly in the search bar, you need to copy the value of it into a local variable, modify that variable, then assign that to the frame property of the search bar. Line 3 of the sample code shows this.